# Linking GSL using CMake, undefined symbols

Tags: c++, cmake, gsl

I'm attempting to link GSL to my C++ code using cmake, and all goes well until I attempt to build. CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

include_directories(${project_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
link_directories(${project_BINARY_DIR}/src)

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem unit_test_framework REQUIRED )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )

find_package(GSL REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set (lib_SOURCES
    ../src/file.h
    ../src/file.cpp
    # etc
     )

target_include_directories(project PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} ${GSL_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(sigma OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX GSL::gsl GSL:gslcblas)
```

When I add `#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>` and call something from the library in the C++, e.g. a  `gsl_integration_workspace * w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000);`, at the `make` I get an `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:...`, so the library isn't linking, but I don't know why. CMake clearly recognises GSL, but isn't liking to it.

I'm on Big Sur 11.3.1, GSL 2.6 installed via homebrew.

Comment: GSL:gslcblas maybe it miss a ":" no?

Comment: In the `CMakeLists.txt` you show there is no `add_library` or `add_executable` calls, which are responsible for compilation and linking. Please, post the **correct** code (preferrable in form of [mcve]) and **complete** error message it causes.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by removing my CMakeCache.txt files and running cmake again.

I realized this as I was preparing minimal working example in response to Tsyvarev's comment. I hope this can help somebody.